# Get Values of Parameters of a Method Regardless their number or type C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, methodinfo

I want to get the values of parameters of any method even if they have different number of parameters using C#
for example if you have 3 methods as the following:

```
public void method1 (string param1)
{
    List<string> parametervalues = getParameters(this.Method);
}
public void method2 (int param1, string param2)
{
    List<string> parametervalues = getParameters(this.Method);
}
public void method3 (string param1, int param2, bool param3)
{
    List<string> parametervalues = getParameters(this.Method);
}
```

so in getParameters method it will take the methodname and return as a list of strings the values of the parameters regardless number of the parameter is there.

i reached a point that i can get the number of parameters but without values as the following

```
var method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
var parameters = method.GetParameters();
List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
if (parameters.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var p in parameters)
    {
        parameterList.Add(p.Name);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have found a another way by using (params object[] values) as method parameter as the following

```
method1(string a, string b, string c)
{
list<string> = getParameterasList(a,b,c);
}

getParameterasList(params object[] values)
{
            List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
            if (values.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var v in values)
                {
                    parameterList.Add(v.ToString());
                }
            }
return parameterList;
}
```

Comment: You can't get the *values* of the parameters through reflection.

Comment: is thir a way to get the values using another way but reflection?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164165.aspx). Warning: it will take time to go through this, understand it, and implement it correctly. Once you see the basics of intercepting calls and can implement it, you'll be able to get the values of method parameters.

In a nutshell, interception is the process of intercepting calls to methods, doing something that you want to happen before the call, then let the call actually happen, then you get a chance to do something with the call on the way back out to the caller.

It would be difficult to show you a complete example here, but follow that link and you'll be fine. During interception, this is how we got the values of method parameters when an exception is returned from a method. (You'll have access to an `IMethodCallMessage`, which has the info you need.) We do this so we can log the method parameters:

```
    private static List<ParameterInformation> GetParameterInfoList(IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
    {
        var = new List<ParameterInformation>();

        // Note: This works even if a parameter's value is null.
        for(int i = 0 ; i < methodCallMessage.ArgCount ; i++)
        {
            parameterInformationList.Add(new ParameterInformation(methodCallMessage.GetArgName(i), methodCallMessage.Args[i]));
        }

        return parameterInformationList;
    }
```

Comment: The link you posted goes to "MSDN Magazine Issues"

Comment: It didn't 4.5 years ago.